# image and text inside UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to add a text and an image inside a UITabbarItem but it didn't work when I used UITabBarItem inside the Navigation Bar.
So, I have added UIButton inside the Navigation Bar and set image and title for it like this:

[Click to see example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCypC.png)

Here is what I did :

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "sortIc"), for: .normal)
button.setTitle("ترتيب",for: .normal)

button.sizeToFit()

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

What I want to do is to change the place of the image to the text place and vice versa. Any suggestions ?

Comment: where you want to add button on Navigation Bar?

Comment: @KhawarIslam ..I want the button to be added on the rightBarButton .... self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button).

Comment: try to make more simple code.

Comment: you want to assign one thing it should bi image or text?

Comment: But its so clear that I want to use them both ! 
However I guess this is the simplest way to add an image and a text for a button !!

Comment: wait i am checking on my machine